# Return first item in list if FirstOrDefault returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I've got a `List` of products, I need to get the item from the list with a specific product `Id` that I get from a querystring parameter. However, I may not always have a product `Id` passed to me. If I don't have a product `Id`, I need to default to the first product in the list.

At the moment I have:

```
@Model.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId);
```

This just selects the product with that specific `Id`, if there isn't one, it will default to `null`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
var product = productId == null ? Model.Products.FirstOrDefault()
                    : Model.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId);
...
@product
```

or you could mean:

```
@(Model.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId) ??
             Model.Products.FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: +1 I think I prefer the second part of your answer over mine (and in reality I would probably code it like this, especially if I knew I was going to have to maintain it, but I've worked with people who say stuff like "WTF does the double question mark mean?!" so sometimes the path of least resistance is easiest...).

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try something like this?

```
@if (productId != null) // assuming it's nullable
{
  @Model.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId)
} 
else 
{
  @Model.Products.FirstOrDefault()
}
```

I know this may look a little cumbersome, but it's quite clear what it's doing (think if somebody else has to maintain it) and it should work.

But in reality I'd probably rather set this up in a `ViewModel` and then just access the value which I knew would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Check this  it may help you

**MSDN link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx**

```
List<int> months = new List<int> { };

            // Setting the default value to 1 after the query.
            int firstMonth1 = months.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstMonth1 == 0)
            {
                firstMonth1 = 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The value of the firstMonth1 variable is {0}", firstMonth1);

            // Setting the default value to 1 by using DefaultIfEmpty() in the query.
            int firstMonth2 = months.DefaultIfEmpty(1).First();
            Console.WriteLine("The value of the firstMonth2 variable is {0}", firstMonth2);

            /*
             This code produces the following output:

             The value of the firstMonth1 variable is 1
             The value of the firstMonth2 variable is 1
            */
```