# FirstOrDefault in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to move this foreach loop to linq:

```
compData = componentData[0];
foreach (var componentTraceData in componentData)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(componentTraceData.CompName))
     {
          compData = componentTraceData;
          break;
     }
}
```

And this is what I tried:

```
var tt = (from n in componentData 
          where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n.CompName) 
          select n).FirstOrDefault();
```

How I can make it to take `componentData[0]` in case linq not found any results ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return first item in list if FirstOrDefault returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429341/return-first-item-in-list-if-firstordefault-returns-null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) and specify a custom default value:

```
var result = componentData.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n.CompName))
                          .DefaultIfEmpty(componentData.ElementAtOrDefault(0))
                          .First();
```

Note that you can now use [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976) safely since the sequence cannot be empty anymore. [`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will return `default(T)`(null for reference types) if the source sequence is empty. This will prevent an exception when you use the indexer of an `IList<T>` directly.

Answer (score 11):

Take the line you currently have and add `?? componentData[0]` at the end.

`??` is the null coalescing operator.  It's just shorthand for, "if what's to my left is null, return what's on my right.  If it's not null, return that."

Comment: [`default(t)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is only null for reference types.

Comment: @TimSchmelter True, but I highly doubt he's using a struct here.  You are correct that it doesn't generalize quite as well though.

Answer (score 2):

```
var tt = componentData.FirstOrDefault(n=!string.IsNullOrEmpty(n.CompName)) ?? componentData[0];
```

Although you would want to check that `componentData` was not null and `count`/`length` was greater than zero first too.